# Horizontal scrollIntoView only

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get last step here intoView,
but not lose the Title, (cose scrollIntoView scrolls vertically as well)

how to achieve that it scrolls into view only horizontally not vertically

```
const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
  const activeStep = document.querySelector(".ant-steps-item- 
  current");

  if (activeStep) {
    activeStep.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", inline: 
  "center" });
   }
    }, []);

  return (
   <div style={{ minHeight: "200vh" }}>
    <div style={{ height: "150px", fontSize: 
    "5rem"}}>Title</div>
  <Steps>
    {steps.map((s, step) => {
      const status = s === "step9" ? "current" : "";
      return (
        <Steps.Step status={status} key={step} title={s} 
    description={s} />
       );
       })}
   </Steps>
  </div>
```

);
};

you can see an [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-forked-x2sov?file=/index.js)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code into the question, not an external link.

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to say. As far as I have understood you want to avoid vertical scroll bar. Add body{ overflow-y: hidden} in your index.css file

Comment: Element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded() could be useful too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded

Answer (score 32):

It looks like you've already done this in your code sandbox, but adding the block: 'nearest' property should solve this in most cases. scrollIntoView will still attempt to bring the element into view vertically, but it won't try to vertically center it.

```
activeStep.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'center' })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: This is helpful, but IMO does not answer the question: "how to scroll into view only horizontally, not vertically"

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for others, but it does work for my case and it's now only scrolling horizontally :)

Answer (score 2):

```
const scrollIntoViewHorizontally = (
  container,
  child,
) => {
  const child_offsetRight = child.offsetLeft + child.offsetWidth;
  const container_scrollRight = container.scrollLeft + container.offsetWidth;

  if (container.scrollLeft > child.offsetLeft) {
    container.scrollLeft = child.offsetLeft;
  } else if (container_scrollRight < child_offsetRight) {
    container.scrollLeft += child_offsetRight - container_scrollRight;
  }
};

scrollIntoViewHorizontally(scrollContainer, child);
```

```js
const scrollIntoViewHorizontally = (container,child) => {
  const child_offsetRight = child.offsetLeft + child.offsetWidth;
  const container_scrollRight = container.scrollLeft + container.offsetWidth;

  if (container.scrollLeft > child.offsetLeft) {
    container.scrollLeft = child.offsetLeft;
    return;
  }

  if (container_scrollRight < child_offsetRight) {
    container.scrollLeft += child_offsetRight - container_scrollRight;
  }
};

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(!e.target.classList.contains('tab')) {
   return;
  }
  scrollIntoViewHorizontally(e.currentTarget, e.target);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.tab {
  display: flex;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.tab:hover, .tab:focus {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p>Press a tab to return it back into view</p>

<div class="container">
  <button class="tab">tab 1</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 2</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 3</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 4</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 5</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 6</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 7</button>
  <button class="tab">tab 8</button>
</div>
```